# Automatically adding default text to column when new row is added google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script that will trigger whenever a new row is added to my sheet, and add a text to column f in the new row only. I have the following script, but it didn't work. Would love your help. Thanks so much!

```
    function myFunction(e) {
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
 var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
 sh.getRange(row, 6).setValue('defaultValue')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is excellent, I was able to make it work, however I notice that in order to make it work you need to make sure to add a trigger.

In this case "onChange". [On App Script Make sure to go add a trigger for this function to work over the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtYCz.png)

Comment: Once you do that, just add a new row over the Spreadsheet and it should show you the "defaultValue" over column F and the row it was added.

Comment: yes it does thanks, missed that part the trigger I put is on open not on change.

Comment: Awesome, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: another thing that seems to work if I am the one making the change, not by google forms for example, or anyone have the editing permision

Comment: Interesting, I would assume that this can also be modified to work with "onEdit", happy to help.

Comment: how to modify it,if you don't mind me asking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241671/discussion-between-shady-m-rasmy-and-ricardo-jose-velasquez-cruz).

Answer (score 1):

You can add triggers programmatically

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}

function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
    var row = ss.getActiveRange().getRow();
    ss.getRange(row, 6).setValue('defaultValue')
  }
}
```

That's because the onChange trigger is [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and you can do it from the user interface or with the code above. The `formSubmit` and `onEdit` work in the same way.